What's the recommended way to click away from a dialog with Playwright?
I'm writing a web app that uses Mantine's <Modal> dialog component. The modal shows an overlay on the background when opened. Clicking on the overlay causes it to close.
I am trying to write a Playwright test that needs to close the dialog by clicking on the overlay. What's the recommended way of clicking outside an element in Playwright?
Here's an example dialog:
import { Button, MantineProvider, Modal } from "@mantine/core";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(true);
  return (
    <MantineProvider>
      <Button onClick={() => setOpened(true)}>Open modal</Button>
      <Modal opened={opened} onClose={() => setOpened(false)}>
        This is a modal!
      </Modal>
    </MantineProvider>
  );
}

The best solution I've come up with is using locator.click()'s position option on the page's <body> element to click in the corner of the viewport, like so:
await page.locator("body").click({ position: { x: 0, y: 0 } });

This works, but it feels hacky. I shouldn't need to specify a location where the dialog is not covering. I'd imagine there's some recommended way to do this.

Does your dialog has a backdrop? Maybe it is possible to locate the backdrop and click on it, this would trigger the click away listener I think.

Depends on the site. Most modals work by having an overlay obscuring the rest of the page beneath the dialog. I'd click that. What script are you trying to write? Web scraping or testing?

I'm using a component library (Mantine), so I'd rather not have to rely on the implementation details of 3rd-party software.

I don't think you'd be testing significant implementation details if you click an overlay--having to choose a particular locator (still may be user-visible) isn't tying you down all that much. If you switch libraries, you can change the locator easily to whatever the new overlay locator is, worst case scenario. I suppose you could get the modal's bounding box left side, for example, and click a few pixels to the left, but you might be overthinking this a bit--if the gymnastics necessary to avoid locating a modal overlay are this intense, better just pick a locator and don't overthink it.

Anyway, showing a code example of the modal you're actually dealing with, and a simple test case, would make it easier to answer this. See [mcve]. There is no page.locator(".my-modal").clickOutsideOf() method.

Yeah, I guess I probably am overthinking this @ggorlen, thanks for your comments. I've added an MCVE to my question.

Thanks. MCVE needs to be in the question itself.

Links disappear over time, so once the sandbox goes, future visitors won't find much value in the question. Putting the code into the question itself is like checking it into version control--we have a definite code sample and package versions to make the question concrete and reproducible going forward.

Ok, but I don't understand the value in putting the code I wrote for the sandbox into my question: it's completely unrelated to Playwright & locators because the implementation details of the dialog are all in the Mantine package.

Not really--you have a package that offers you a modal and you want to know what the best approach to test it is. A MCVE involves the modal you're testing and a full test case that tests it, a package.json, and a question about all of that. The answer I'd offer is probably that a simple locator like page.locator(".mantine-Modal-overlay").click() is not a significant "implementation detail" or real problem as you may assume. You're not relying on library internals, just a class name. Worst case scenario you use a different modal or upgrade and the test breaks, so you update the class.

(Sorry, I'm new to this.) So are you saying my question should really be "How should I click away from a Mantine modal in Playwright?" Should I just edit this question or delete it and ask a new one?

No, keep the question and don't make it so specific. It's fine to ask how to click away from a dialog, but there also needs to be context. See my first comment: it depends on the site--going into that, I didn't even know that you're using a third party library or not. It's OK to ask a general question, but there needs to be specific context and a MCVE to avoid an XY problem wherein people tell you how to click outside an element, but that's not necessarily the best solution to your actual problem.

It's also very common, especially in scraping, that general solutions don't work on specific cases. I post speculative answers and OP comes back with "it's not working for me", and it turns out there's something they never mentioned on their actual page or particularly library (or library version) that makes the solution fail for them--so I won't bother answering unless I have a pretty good idea we're on the same page (literally: running the same code, automating the same site, using the same packages). Otherwise, it's just a waste of time for everyone.

Also, it's a pain to rewrite code that you presumably already have (the test suite and a minimal example of the app). I write fully working code for most of my answers and test it, and having something ready to work off of makes it easy to avoid reinventing your code (prone to errors in addition to taking time).

I've edited the question [again]. But now it feels like I'm asking 2 questions-"is there a way to 'click outside' in Playwright?" and "how should I do it for a Mantine dialog?"

I don't know if this can help you but I was trying to do unit testing for a Mantine modal without a close button, what I did was add an aria-label to the overlayProps:
<Modal
    opened={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    title={`Search`}
    overlayProps={{
        'aria-label': 'modal-backdrop',
    }}
    withCloseButton={false}
>

After that, I simply needed to get the backdrop element by the aria-label which I did by doing
const backdrop = document.querySelector('[aria-label="modal-backdrop"]');

After that, I just needed to fire a userEvent to click the element, which worked
await userEvent.click(backdrop);

It isn't specifically e2e testing with Playwright, but hopefully you'll be able to simulate the user closing the modal by being able to get the backdrop with an aria-label

There is a prop called closeOnClickOutside for the Modal component in Mantine UI.
By default, modal will close on outside click, but if you want to stop that behaviour, you can simply set false to the closeOnClickOutside prop.
You can check official documentation for more details.
If you want to stop closing modal on outside click, you can try as below.
 <Modal opened={opened} onClose={close} title="Authentication" closeOnClickOutside={false} >
    {/* Modal content */}
 </Modal>


I don't want to prevent the modal from closing on click outside, I want Playwright to simulate a click outside.
